# Single-word synonym for a  “pedantic rule-follower”?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

What do you call a person who always follows the rules, at the expense of everything else?  I’m thinking there’s one word that can describe this, but I can’t place it.

Comment: Although it's mentioned in your title, [*pedant*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedant) ("a formalist or precisionist in teaching") might suit your needs. Otherwise, [*formalist*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/formalist?show=0&t=1349287992) (from *formalism*: "the practice or the doctrine of strict adherence to prescribed or external forms (as in religion or art)") could work, in addition to Robusto's answer.

Comment: Although it isn't exactly what you're looking for, I love the word [myrmidon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/myrmidon).

Comment: I haven't heard it used, but I'd be inclined to coin an eponym and call him or her a "[Javert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javert)"

Comment: A lot of great answers here, so I'll just add a comment. I think a shortening of the word _dogmatist_ is in order: how about a  **dogmat**? (Similar to a _doormat_: "one that submits without protest to abuse or indignities").

Comment: Oh, this is easy, you call him **Sheldon Cooper**

Comment: A “German”. There, that was easy. [And yes, friends actually do apply that word to especially rule-following people “oh come on, don’t be so German!”]

Comment: This question has generated so much discussion, I'm giving the question an upvote just on that basis. :-)

Comment: Yes, if John has asked this question as part of a sociology experiment, I think he deserves an A (i.e., top grade, for foreigners).  I don't know how you could pick a single response and call it the right answer.  @Konrad: true, but "German" risks being understood as Nazi. In the end, I think the winner is "dogmat," a new word that expresses the sense perfectly!

Comment: Would "over-obedient" work?  reference: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/over-obedient

Comment: [Definite duplicate](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4732/2085).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A [*jobsworth*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/jobsworth#jobsworth_5) is “someone who always obeys the rules of their job exactly, even when it would be more sensible not to”.

Comment: from the phrase "it's more than my job's worth" to break the rules and do what you want. In other words I might be fired for letting you get away with something, and I'm not willing to risk it.

Comment: Wiki gives a rather difference meaning to the term. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jobsworth )

Comment: This answers the question more accurately than stickler, as usually stickler requires "for xxx" after it. +1 from me.

Comment: If anyone is still listening : "Jobsworth" seems to fit. Its a British term commonly used in newspapers in the 80's and 90's. A contraction of "It's more than my job's worth" it is used to describe a petty official hiding behind regulations to save themselves work or cause aggravation to members of the public. e.g. "It may be an emergency, but it's more than my job's worth to let you use the office phone...."

Answer (score 42):

You could say the person is a *stickler* (sometimes clarified with *for*: “a stickler for the rules”, “a stickler for accuracy”, “a stickler for grammar”) if you mean they enforce rules or process that others don't.

Comment: Yes. Stickler might not carry the connotation of "at the expense of everything else" though. More "because rules must not be broken".

Answer (score 26):

[*The Free Dictionary Online*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/doctrinaire) would say that person is:

> **doctrinaire**
>   *n.*
>   A person inflexibly attached to a practice or theory without regard to its practicality.

This is also the adjective form. An alternative noun form is *doctrinarian*.

Comment: I would say *doctrinaire* applies more to following dogma (doctrine), rather than rules. But it's very similar: it does have the connotation of disregard for practicalities.

Comment: Is the word still used with connotations of (religious) doctrine? Or is it mainstream in just the rule-follower sense?

Comment: "The word doctrinaire has become naturalized in English terminology, as applied, in a slightly contemptuous sense, to a theorist, as distinguished from a practical man of affairs." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrinaires)

Comment: ahh, so this is the result of being indoctrinated

Answer (score 21):

A *legalist*.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/legalist?s=t

Also, in Biblical usage, a *Pharisee*.

Comment: +1 for Pharisee. That would be a colorful choice indeed.

Comment: +1 for Pharisee. Sounds less bland than legalist. Unless you want them to be labeled as bland ;)

Comment: _Pharisee_ was exactly the word that kept swirling around on the tip of my tongue. +1 for helping me gargle it out!

Answer (score 15):

I’ve encountered a few people that you describe. Often, they were *bureaucrats*:

> An official who is *rigidly* devoted to the *details of administrative procedure*.[¹](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bureaucrat)

Comment: I just logged on to give this answer (after pondering the question all day). +1

Comment: Good possibility, though I think you'd have to qualify it some. If you just say that a person is a bureaucrat, I think it would generally be understood to mean, (a) he works for an organization that is rule-bound, without necessarily saying that he himself is; or (b) he works for a government agency, without necessarily connoting how rule-bound he is. Now if you say, "Bob acts like a bueaucrat" or "Wow, Bob certainly plays the role of a bureaucrat", then I think it would have the meaning you're looking for.

Comment: When I lived in Switzerland (a very rule-oriented place), I often encountered "fonctionnaires" (the French word for functionaries). The closest translated (pejorative) meaning I could come up with in English was bureaucrat, since functionary is not vernacular (in North America, anyway).

Answer (score 14):

A *punctilious* person is someone who takes great care to follow rules and instructions.[¹](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/punctilious) *Online Etymology Dictionary* says:

> 1630s, probably from It. *puntiglioso*, from *puntiglio* “fine point,” from L. *punctum* “prick”[²](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=punctilious)

Comment: I wonder if the Latin translation had the same connotation that it does today. :)

Comment: @John FWIW, "puntiglioso" is an actual Italian word today. Depending on the context it has a negative or positive connotation, but the meaning is the same it had in Latin.

Comment: The same in Spanish _"puntilloso"_

Answer (score 14):

The noun-form of the adjective in your question’s title should suffice: *pedant*.

Comment: A *pedant* (in the negative sense) is particularly concerned with trivialities, which is a different shade of meaning. Not to be pedantic or anything.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if slang is allowed in here (will let the downvotes reveal to me) but this is most classically defined (at least in the IT/hacker world) as being *[anal](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/anal-retentive)* (short version of “[anal retentive](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal_retentive)”).

(Warning: this should not be used in a formal conversation, and might be derogatory or offensive.)

Comment: Slang is fine ... It may not be the intended meaning, though. It has more properties than are called for: "fixation at this stage is said to result in orderliness, meanness, stubbornness, compulsiveness, etc." (*WordNet*)

Answer (score 9):

I'm guessing you're thinking of *dogmatic* because it’s a fairly common term, the sort that would perch right there on the tip of your tongue. It’s not the best term in the answers given so far, however.

Comment: I don't see how this word fits with what OP is asking? _"[...]a person who always follows the rules, at the expense of everything else[...]"_ (IMO) Dogmatic doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @Souta: I think the suggestion is fine. (Sure, it's the "wrong" part of speech, but it easily leads to **dogmatist**, which fits fine. As my uncle used to say, "Just give me the right adjective – I can find the right noun from there.")

Comment: @J.R. I hadn't thought of it like that. My apologies

Answer (score 8):

If we focus on the “at the expense of everything else” part of your question, both *fanatic* and the previously mentioned *zealot* are good options. Adjectival variations include *fanatical rule-follower*, *a fanatic for X*, etc.

From a different perspective, a [*martinet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martinet#Martinet_as_a_person) is a strict rule-follower, but the term is [less used](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=martinet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) nowadays. *Martinet* has a pseudo-military connotation and draws focus to making other people follow the rules.

Comment: "Martinet" is a great suggestion. It's likely to be unfamiliar, but of all the words suggested here, I think it is the only one that captures the precise meaning the OP is looking for.

Comment: To me, a *martinet* is most concerned with *enforcing* the rules; whether he himself follows them is a different matter.

Comment: @Martha Yeah, I'm having my doubts about this suggestion.  "Martinet" came from the name of an actual drill sergeant.  And drill sergeants don't actually do their own drills.

Answer (score 6):

If that person is also very bad at poetry, you can use the term *Vogon*.

Comment: I always thought of Vogons as alien Nazis...

Comment: I'm not sure why there is a downvote here.  The single most defining characteristic of a Vogon is their unreasonable reliance on bureaucratic rules and formalities.  That, and their bad poetry.  I think calling someone a Vogon in this case would be witty and accurate, though not everyone may understand the reference.

Answer (score 5):

If you were using this term in a gaming context, that person would be known as a "[rules lawyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_lawyer)".

Answer (score 3):

You would say that the person is *orthodox*.

American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition, reads:

> Orthodox: adj. Adhering to what is commonly accepted, customary, or traditional: an orthodox view of world affairs.

Comment: It's true OED includes an entry saying *orthodox* can be used as a "standalone" noun - defined as *a member of the Orthodox Eastern Church, an orthodox Jew*, and (obs.) *an orthodox opinion* as well as the more generic *an orthodox person*. But I've never come across it thus used.

Comment: Well... I think the definition you quote is good, and nothing about that definition implies an adherence to rules over practicality or common sense. If I say, e.g., that someone is an "orthodox doctor", I think that would be understood to me that he believes in treating patients with medicine and surgery, as opposed to aroma therapy, acupuncture, faith healing, etc. But he might be very flexible in his application of the rules of his craft. Indeed, the term is most often used in connection with religion, and if you call someone an "orthodox Baptist", any Baptist I know would understand ...

Comment: ... that to mean that he rejects the idea of rigid adherance to rules and believes in salvation by grace.

Comment: "orthodox" doesn't usually carry the negative connotation of "at the expense of everything else."

Comment: I partially disagree with the commenters; it does have a slight connotation of sticking to rules at the expense of better things.

Answer (score 3):

A *bigot* comes to mind.

Also, *Zealot* (close to Pharisee) might work

(non native here)

Comment: _Zealot_ works well. Bigotry is often associated with racism, so _bigot_ may not be as strong a candidate, but the dictionary backs  you up.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. I'd never actually heard of _bigot_ in that context. I think I only ever saw it in 'technical' contexts ("That is (not|only) for (functional programming|OOP) _bigots_")

Comment: Hmm. "Bigot" is normally defined as one is intolerant of others based on race, religion, politics, etc. I don't see any connection to being rule-bound. A "Zealot" is -- skipping over the literal meaning -- one who is excessive or fanatic about some cause. That cause COULD involve following a rulebook, but not necessarily. It wouldn't be an oxymoron to call someone an "anarchist Zealot".

Answer (score 2):

You could say such a person is *[lawful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lawful)*.

> Conforming to, permitted by, or recognised by law or rules.

Comment: True, but I think this usage is mostly limited to people who play Dungeons & Dragons.

Comment: At the expense of everything else (for law's sake): Lawful Neutral; perversely (for harm's sake): Lawful Evil.

Comment: But only incidentally.

Comment: For those who don't play D&D, *legalist* (already given in another answer) probably serves this purpose better.

Answer (score 2):

A *nazi*? (In the “soup nazi” sense.)

Comment: Because when I think Nazi, I think someone who follows the rules.

Comment: To the OP: be very careful how you use this word.  If you're not sure whether it's appropriate in a particular situation, you would be safer to avoid it.

Comment: @EvanCaroll  It's not the literal or core sense of Nazi, and it will offend listeners in all but the most familiar contexts (as will most 4 letter words), but it's certainly a common enough one to mention, especially in derived adjective-type constructions like a "cleanliness Nazi" or a "Nazi about cleanliness".

Comment: the most common form of this, AFAICT, is **Grammar Nazi**.

Comment: I don't see the word as being a "pedantic rules follower" but rather a "rules enforcer".

Comment: @ ghoppe You have a point there. I realize I see that word as both...

Comment: In any case, it only works with an accompanying qualifier, like "grammar Nazi" or "timesheet Nazi". If you just say "Bob is a Nazi", I think people will assume you mean that in a socio/political sense, that he is, if not actually a member of a Nazi group, a fascist and/or racist, and not that he is a stickler for trivial rules. In any circles I've moved in that would be a pretty serious insult.

Comment: Calling somebody a *concept*-nazi implies that they are *sadistic* or *ruthless* in their enforcement of the rules, rather than simply pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an informal or mildly insulting word, try *anal.*

> Suzy is *anal* about political discussions in the office.

Answer (score 2):

A “pedantic rule-follower” is called a tautology, because pedantic means rule-follower, so if you aren't on the search for **tautology**, you are searching a **pedant**.

Comment: Tautology is needless repetition.

Comment: Isn't that that what I wrote?

Comment: That's not how it came across.

Comment: @Luke: Needless repetition. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure of the original question, but id say that the best word for "rule follower, " is bureaucrat. God dammed bureaucrat. No skilled, bastards. Live in stale cubicles, starring at a computer all day, smelling someones leftover dinner being reheated in the break room microwave. Dreaming up rules for others to follow. Can you tell I'm self employed?